# AWS Amplify support for APIs with query string (image components having strapi urls with query sting not loading/ being ignored)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, query-string, aws-amplify, strapi

I have hosted a Next js app (version 14.x, with node 20 (app routing)) in aws amplify (from github) that uses Strapi as Headless CMS.

I am ***unable to access*** any cms content from stapi that has a ***query string*** in the api.

**Sample API call**

`{{Base_URL}}/contact-us?populate=deep&locale=en`

Amplify seems to be blocking the calls as I am not able to see any request coming to strapi logs.

The Next js project seems to work flawlessly in my local machine. The issue persists only for the amplify hosted app.

I have already gone through several posts with similar scenarios, but none of the solutions seem to work.

I have already tried editing Rewrites and redirects which didnt work. Currently it is as below.

```
[
    {
        "source": "https://....xxx", /*Actual url differs*/
        "target": "https://www...xxx",
        "status": "302",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404-200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Please suggest a feasible solution.